# ansible list from file as variable

Tags: ansible

could you please help me to add NTP address as variable , this is vmware ntp server update and i am trying to pass NTP server address as variable.

**var file content**

```
cat var.yml
NTP_Servers:
        - 192.168.10.20
        - 192.168.10.21
```

**Playbook file**

```
- name: Add NTP to host on specified portgroup
  local_action:
    module: vmware_host_ntp
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip}}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
    esxi_hostname: "{{ item.value.mgmtip }}"
    ntp_servers:                                 <<<<<<<<<IP ADDRESS>
    state: present
  with_dict: "{{ PayloadNodes | default({}) }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags: NTP
```

Comment: Have you tried to just pass the variable as you did for other keywords, anyway you are supposed to have at least tried something and provide what you tried with the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the contents of the file as a variable, you can either: use [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html) on the task level

```
- name: Add NTP to host on specified portgroup
include_vars: var.yaml
```

or use [vars_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) on the playbook level

```
---
hosts: netservers
vars_files:
  - var.yml
```